# SQL select all purchases that contain at least two products from a alist

Tags: sql, databricks-sql

I would like to write a SQL query to retrieve all transactions (DOCUMENT_NUM) that contain at least two products from a selection list ("A", "B", "C")

```
select TRANSACTION_DAY, DOCUMENT_NUM, PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_DSCR, QTY_SOLD, NET_SALES
from main.sales
where PRODUCT_CODE in ("A", "B", "C")
```

If I use the IN operator, the query may return transactions with one product from the list, but I want at least two.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to achieve that using `group by` and `count`

```
select distinct DOCUMENT_NUM
from main.sales
where PRODUCT_CODE in ("A", "B", "C")
group by DOCUMENT_NUM
having count(distinct PRODUCT_CODE)>=2
```

If you need all the columns, you can do a nested query

```
select TRANSACTION_DAY, DOCUMENT_NUM, PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_DSCR, QTY_SOLD, NET_SALES
from main.sales
where DOCUMENT_NUM in (
  select distinct DOCUMENT_NUM
  from main.sales
  where PRODUCT_CODE in ("A", "B", "C")
  group by DOCUMENT_NUM
  having count(distinct PRODUCT_CODE)>=2
)
and PRODUCT_CODE in ("A", "B", "C")
```

Comment: @Parfait Yes, it works in [databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/count.html)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, consider [**`approx_count_distinct`**](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions/approx_count_distinct.html) (faster than `COUNT`+`DISTINCT` for larger datasets) to filter `DOCUMENT_NUM` by distinct `PRODUCT_CODE`:

```sql
select TRANSACTION_DAY, DOCUMENT_NUM, 
       PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_DSCR, 
       QTY_SOLD, NET_SALES 
from main.sales 
where DOCUMENT_NUM IN (
   select DOCUMENT_NUM
   from main.sales
   group by DOCUMENT_NUM
   having approx_count_distinct(PRODUCT_CODE) 
          filter(where PRODUCT_CODE in ("A", "B", "C")) >= 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include transactions that have at least two of the same products as well, see code below.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id INT
, cat CHAR)

INSERT INTO test(id, cat)
VALUES (1, 'a')
, (2, 'a')
, (3, 'a')
, (1, 'b')
, (2, 'a')
, (3, 'c')

SELECT id
, COUNT(id)
FROM test
WHERE cat IN ('a', 'b')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

If you only want transactions that have 2 or more unique products use below code to replace last block of code above:

```
SELECT id
, COUNT(id)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM test) t
WHERE cat in ('a', 'b')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```